# JS+Jquery recursion with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am stuck with a problem. I am trying to write some code with recursion. Each time button is clicked order get + 1 and console should print  1, 2, 3, 4 ... n, but instead it gets 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 
My code:

```
function f(order) {
            console.log(order);
            order++;
            $("#btn").on("click", function() {
                    f(order);
                }
            )}

f(1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var order = 0;

function f() {
    order++;
}
$("#btn").on("click", f);
```

You don't need to pass the order as a parameter to your function if you have it in the scope your function is. This way you can have much more legible code.

Comment: There is error in your code. It should look like this:

    var order = 0;

    function f() {
            order++;
    }
    $("#btn").on("click", f);

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clear enough. Let me know if you need explanation.

```
order = 0;
function f() {
        console.log(order);
        order++;
}
$("#btn").on("click", f);
```